# Vagrant SSH works on existing box but not new box

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have successfully worked with Vagrant 2.2.4 on Windows 10 for years. I had created a custom box based on Ubuntu 14.04 and am able to log in using `vagrant ssh`.

I created a new test project to try using a new box:

```
$ mkdir ~/vagrant_test
$ cd ~/vagrant_test
$ vagrant init ubuntu/jammy64
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

I edited the `Vagrantfile` to have minimal options:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
end
```

However, `vagrant up` fails on the test project:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/jammy64' version '20230314.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
The private key you're attempting to use with this Vagrant box uses
an unsupported encryption type. The SSH library Vagrant uses does not support
this key type. Please use `ssh-rsa` or `ssh-dss` instead. Note that
sometimes keys in your ssh-agent can interfere with this as well,
so verify the keys are valid there in addition to standard
file paths.
```

**Test project:**

```
$ cd ~/vagrant_test
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

**Working existing project with custom box:**

```
$ cd ~/job_tracker
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/boxes/seaportstainless-VAGRANTSLASH-job_tracker/1.0.0/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

**Attempted SSH into test project box:**

```
$ cd ~/vagrant_test
$ vagrant ssh -- -v
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2200.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key type -1
debug1: identity file C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2200 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:YLUw1a2RC1Dm4YAbjyXxg8BiH3vWZ8okfVT3hDgTKik
debug1: checking without port identifier
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2200' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key':
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**Edit 4/12/23:**
I tried to manually SSH into the new Vagrant box and got a remote host warning:

```
$ ssh -i /c/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:********************
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /c/Users/Ryan/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /c/Users/Ryan/.ssh/known_hosts:7
ECDSA host key for [127.0.0.1]:2222 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I removed `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` from known_hosts, and then I was able to manually SSH into the new Vagrant box:

```
$ ssh -i /c/Users/Ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:2222 ([127.0.0.1]:2222)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:**************.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-69-generic x86_64)
```

However, I still get the same "unsupported encryption type" error when trying to log in via `vagrant ssh`.

Comment: I don't know Vagrant. Do you use the same key pair for the old and new VM? How did you create the SSH key pairs? Please copy&paste the **public** keys to the question. Maybe try a recent version of Vagrant. BTW: Ubuntu 14.04 is rather old and no longer supported. Please [edit] your question to provide additional information.

Comment: I didn't create SSH key pairs. I didn't think that manual creation of SSH keys was required with Vagrant. I realize Ubuntu 14.04 is very old, and that's why I am trying to use jammy64 (Ubuntu 22.04). I edited the question with more information.